# How to replace the value of '0' in a given pattern?

Tags: java

I am new in java, and i am trying to replace the value of "0's" with "x" at index "0,1,7,13,20,21,22, and 23" in below given sequence of 0 and 1's. And the code so far is given. Their is some problem due to which i can not obtain desired result.

001111
101110
100010
110000

```
public class Task {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        File file = new File("C:\\NetBeansProjects\\Task\\src\\File.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String text = null;

            //Array lis declaration
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

            while( (text = reader.readLine()) != null){
                list.add(text);
                }
            //printing Array list.
            System.out.println("Print Array list\n");
            for(String d:list){
               // System.out.println(d);
            }
            //Convert ArrayList into 2DArray
            int noOfLines = 0;
            String[][] array = new String[list.size()][];
            for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
                String row = list.get(i);
                noOfLines++;
                array[i] = row.split("\0");
            }

            System.out.println("Befor");
            print(array);

            int row=0,column=0;
            for(int count=0; count<array.length; count++){
                if(row<noOfLines-1 && array[row+1][column]=="0"){
                    row++;
                }
                else
                    if(column<array[row].length-1 && array[row][column+1]=="0"){
                        column++;
                    }
                        array[row][column] = "x";
            } 
      //     array[0][0] = "x";
           System.out.println("After");
           print(array);


            //end try Block
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //end Catch Block
    } //end main


    public static void print(String[][] array){

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<array[i].length; j++){
                System.out.print(array[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    } //end function print.

} //end Class
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, are you simply trying to replace or 0's with x's? or is there some kind of pattern you wish to follow?

Comment: And, crucially, what is wrong with your code? Currently this reads like a story, not a question.

Comment: I want to replace the value of '0' in a pattern. Pattern is that only go to consecutive 0's (start from index 0 to last index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is probably in this line:

```
array[i] = row.split("\0");
```

The backslash means that the row is split at the character with value zero, [which is not a character that actually occurs in text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_code_chart).

If you meant to split the row at `"0"`, use `row.split("0")`. If you meant to split the row into characters, use `row.split("")`.

Then, you are using `==` to compare strings. NetBeans should actually warn you that this will not work, and suggest to replace it with `.equals` (eg., `array[row+1][column].equals("0")`)